# Sharepoint: Populate column based on a selection in another column | Merge 2 colums in list

Tags: sharepoint

I am a SP newbie and I am stuck with a problem. I have searched considerably and not come across a solution that does not involve XSL, SPD, Java etc
I don’t have any coding skills or access to SPD. I do have SP 2010 and InfoPath 2010 and am keen to learn

I am trying to do the following:

1. When a user selects their project name from a drop down box, another column auto fills the project prefix
   eg. User selects ‘Project Windows’, then project prefix column looks up and populates ‘WIN’
2. I also want to concatenate /merge two columns 
   Eg. I want to merge Project Prefix with ID = WIN23

I have had a crack at calculated columns but can’t get anything to work!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When editing the form in InfoPath right click on the text box that you want to be auto-filled.
Next to the `Value:` input there is a function button. 
Click on that button to view the available fields and functions to auto-fill that field.
1. Use the `Insert Field or Group` button to find the project prefix column
2. Look at function `Concat` in the `Text` category

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I have tried your suggestion but cant get it to work. Not sure if i am understanding you correctly. Here is what i have tried:

Comment: 1. i have used  Insert Field or Group to add Project Prefix          2. I have used concat(Project Prefix, ID,)                           I Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: once you have added the Concat function and inserted the two fields what shows up as the value when you open the form? Have you confirmed the Project Prefix and ID have values?